# how to unit test polyfilled webcomponents custom element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, web-component, custom-element

I want to unit test my web components which use the `webcomponents.js` polyfill.

My components are made in es6 + scss, and with a build task, I transpile the es6 to es5, process the scss to css and insert both result files in the html file to use my component in my applications with the `HTML Import` functionnality.
Here is an example of a component class for the custom element declaration :

```
class my-component extends HTMLElement {
  createdCallback() {...}
  ... //other component methods

  //getter/setter
  get colors() {
    return this._color;
  }
  set colors(val) {
    this._color = val;
  }
}
```

At this time I've made a test task which can launch a `Karma` server, transpile UT with `babel` and run the UT with `Jasmine`.

All my tests are passing with Chrome, but in IE11, all tests which access the getter/setter or methods are failing...

example:

```
describe...
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.component = document.createElement(COMP_NAME);
  }
  it("should return an array", function() {
    expect(this.component.colors).toEqual(jasmine.any(Array));
  });
});
```

This UT will pass in Chrome, but in IE it will fail with `Expected undefined to equal <jasmine.any(Array)>`

My diagnostic is that the polyfill needs some time to create the component. And in my test I will access the getter of the component before it's been fully created (this why i get undefined...)
I tried to defer the test with

```
setTimeout(() => {
  expect(this.component.colors).to...
});
```

But this work sometimes and sometimes not...

Can somebody tell me how I can fix this ?
As a side note, this doesn't happen with all components. Seems to be only with the one which have many methods/accessors and some logic to run onCreate...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or do you have an example of how to do this? I am struggling with the same situation...

Comment: nope, no solution...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use 'whenDefined' in the beforeEach function?

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  this.component = document.createElement(COMP_NAME);
  customElements.whenDefined(COMP_NAME).then(done)
}
```

then the tests will run after the component will upgrade.

In browsers which are not using the polyfill (like chrome) it's upgrading without any delay.

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#api_reference